# Search for a specific user's items with Searchkick

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, searchkick

I need the ability to search for a user's specific items through has_many associations.

I originally had `searchkick` on my Items model, and now have it on my User model. I also had asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53876417/searching-has-many-association-with-searchkick) a few weeks ago for this same question, however I received no responses and have modified the code quite a bit since then.

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
    searchkick
    has_many :items, -> (user) { unscope(:where).where("(consumer_type = ? and consumer_id = ?))", 'User', user.id) }, fully_load: false, dependent: :destroy

    def search_data
        attributes.merge(
            items: library_items.as_json,
        )
    end
end
```

In my controller, I need the ability to run a query such as: `@results = current_user.items.search('Query')`, so that I return items that only that user has access to.

Currently, when I run something like this in rails console:
    user = User.first
    user.search 'Email'
I get `undefined method 'search' for #

How do I go about correctly setting something like this up? Should I actually put `searchkick` on the Item model? If so, how would I then go about searching

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My approach to this would be to index the `Item` model using Searchkick, as it's easier to achieve your desired result that way, especially if you only want information about the items returned in your results (and not necessarily user data as well).

You could then search the `Item` model using something like:

```
@results = Item.search(
             'Query',
             where: {consumer_type: 'User', consumer_id: current_user.id},
             load:  false
           )
```